# Compare metric with label average

Tags: prometheus, promql

I want to be able to compare a given metric `avg_over_time(metric_1[5m])` to determine whether this value is greater than the average of the other `metric_1` that has some shared label.

For example:

If querying: `avg_over_time(metric_1[5m])`

I want to know if (example result) `metric_1{colour="blue", name="bob"}` is greater than  the average of the rest of the `metric_1{colour="blue"}` but that have a different `{name}`

What's the best way to do this in PromQL?

I tried doing something like `avg_over_time(metric_1[5m]) > avg_over_time(metric_1[30m])` but its not exactly what im looking for (need to compare with values with same colour label but excluding same name)

Thanks for the insights :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following PromQL:

```
scalar(avg_over_time(metric_1{colour="blue", name="bob"}[5m])) - avg(avg_over_time(metric_1{colour="blue"}[5m])) > bool 0
```

Comment: The thing is i want to generalize the query for all possible colours/names, so i dont want to include it on the query

Comment: perhaps i can use `on (colour)` or something of that sort